# Count number of uploaded file

Tags: php

I want to `count` number of uploaded file but I'm unable to get the error if no file had been uploaded. Here is my code for reference:

**html**

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" class="filestyle" data-buttonText="Quotation 1" multiple="multiple">
```

**php**

```
$total = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
if($total > '2'){
    for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++){
        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
        if($tmpFilePath != ""){
           $shortname = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
           $filePath = "uploads/" . date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
           if(!$msgError && move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath)){
                // insert to db and success msg 
        }
    }
} elseif($total < '4') {    
    $msgError[] = "Need to upload 3 Quotations";    
}
if(isset($msgError)){
    $msgErrorString = implode(",",$msgError); 
    header("Location: pr_form.php?msgError=".$msgErrorString."");
}
```

If user upload less than 3 files, the error will not appear. I have other validations for user input. Everything is working except for the file validation. May I know why?

Comment: `$total > '2'` Why you declare `2` as a string?

Comment: will remove the ' '. Sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 1):

First: Remove the `'`

`$total > '2'` should be `$total > 2`

same with `total < 4`

---

Second:

It should be

`count($_FILES)` not `count($_FILES['file']['name'])`

---

So, in your problem ..

> if no file had been uploaded.

```
$total = count($_FILES);
if($total > 2){
    for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++){
        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
        if($tmpFilePath != ""){
           $shortname = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
           $filePath = "uploads/" . date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
           if(!$msgError && move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath)){
                // insert to db and success msg 
        }
    }
} elseif($total < 4 && $total > 0) {    
    $msgError = "Need to upload 3 Quotations";    
}
elseif($total === 0){ //This condition
    $msgError = "No chosen file."; 
}
if(isset($msgError)){
    header("Location: pr_form.php?msgError=".$msgError."");
}
```

And then in your pr_form.php, you should have something like this line..

```
<?php 
   echo $_GET['msgError'];
?>
```

Comment: What if no file is selected? Is the same method apply or I have to use `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE` method

Comment: if no file is selected, `count($_FILES)` is empty .. you can do.. if( empty($_FILES) ) { // codes here.. }

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried your codes. It does not submit the form if no files are selected or upload less than 3 files but the error message is not appear

Comment: I updated my codes. Check/Mark correct my answer if it answers your question or +1 up vote if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I did try your answer but still the same. The error are not display

Comment: What do you mean error is not displaying? Does this redirect you to `pr_form.php` or not? ..Does the `header(...)` function executed on your `if( isset($msgError) )` ?

Comment: If no files are selected, it does not redirect the page to pr_form.php. It will go to the form processing page